# API 18 deprecations

Tags: android, api

Can anybody provide a list of deprications made in Jelly Bean 4.3 (API 18) ?

I had an app on API 16 and I wanted my app to be upgraded to API 18, so please tell me what changes I have to make in my code.

Thanks in advance...

I have tried your valuable suggestions. But let me know how can I check which deprecated features can cause my app to crash as I dont have device with API 18 and emulator is very slow...

Comment: Just build the app with API 18 and run lint.

Comment: Any app written for API 16 will still work on API 18. You do not need to change anything.

Comment: reight click on the project and select properties then click on android then select the api level and ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As laalto said the compiler will warn you for deprecated function but there is also a difference report which may help. The page can be found at http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/18/changes.html

Comment: You linked to the API differences report for API Level 14. The API Level 18 (http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/18/changes.html) and 17 (http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/17/changes.html) reports would be of greater utility in this case.

Comment: Updated the answer, although it only involves changing the API level in the URL.

Comment: boardy

can u tell me how to know which method may cause my app to crash on API 18 and also is there any compatibilty issue for users to download it from playstore?

Comment: When you load the project in Eclipse and select the android target to be API 18, it will show in the errors and warning tab in Eclipse what functions will not compile and any functions that are deprecated. You would then need to Google or check the Android documentation which API call you should be using instead and modify your code accordingly. I can't say what methods would likely cause a crash it would be a full time job probably, it would also depend on what APIs you are accessing and any hardware controls but the IDE should be able to tell you anything you need

Comment: But my projects depends on many private third party APIs, what can I do about them...??

Comment: If the third party APIs provide the source code you would be able to fix and rebuild them for your project, otherwise you are just going to have to check whether the third party APIs are backware compatible to your minimum supported API for your app.

Comment: third party APIs are compatible with my mininmum supported API, but they are not compatible with API 18.
And I wanted that the user having API 18 on his device will also be able to use my app...
As we know, playstore only shows the list of compatible apps only...there are major chances that my app will not available these users(having API 18 devices).

Comment: If the libraries you are using doesn't support your target API of 18, then there's not a lot you can do. Check if the third party library has an update available, if not but you have source code, rebuild it to target API 18, or find another library that provides the same functionality but supports the newer API

Answer (score 2):

Just build your code with SDK 18. The compiler will emit warnings for using deprecated methods or fields.

Comment: i was just wondering the same thing, do you have to update targetapi in manifest for apps on the market?

Comment: Build SDK is not the same as target API level. For Eclipse/ADT based tooling, the build SDK is defined in `project.properties`.